# what is the voucher mean in libdispatch from apple?

Tags: libdispatch

I just read source code of libdispatch, but i found there is a word, "voucher", just appear so many times, but i do not know what it is mean actually.
   So could any tell me the true means of this word, thank you very much for your great help.

Best Regards
Axis

Comment: hi  Shawn,   thank you for your post.  I already find answer from xnu source code.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I just find answer from source code:

```
/*
 * Mach Voucher - an immutable collection of attribute value handles.
 *
 * The mach voucher is such that it can be passed between processes
 * as a Mach port send right (by convention in the mach_msg_header_t’s
 * msgh_voucher field).
 *
 * You may construct a new mach voucher by passing a construction
 * recipe to host_create_mach_voucher().  The construction recipe supports
 * generic commands for copying, removing, and redeeming attribute value
 * handles from previous vouchers, or running attribute-mananger-specific
 * commands within the recipe.
 *
 * Once the set of attribute value handles is constructed and returned,
 * that set will not change for the life of the voucher (just because the
 * attribute value handle itself doesn't change, the value the handle refers
 * to is free to change at will).
 */
```

Best Regards

Axis